# How to link identical GTK::UIManager XML menus?

Tags: xml, perl, gtk, uimanager

My GTK application has the following UIManager XML. Is there a way to link those menus *in the XML*, so that I do not have to repeat myself?

```
<ui>
    <menubar name="MenuBar">
        <menu action="Options">
            <menuitem action="Item0"/>
            <menuitem action="Item1"/>
        </menu>
    </menubar>
    <popup name="ContextMenu">
        <menu action="Options">
            <menuitem action="Item0"/>
            <menuitem action="Item1"/>
        </menu>
    </popup>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the repeated parts into a separate file, then use [entities or XInclude](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/07/31/xinclude.html) to include them.

Comment: +1, that's an awesome solution - I'm just not 100% sure it works because GTK might parse these files according to GMarkup, a subset of XML that doesn't support XInclude, but I don't know.

Comment: Subset of XML… `o_O` Let me strike another one on the "Gnome developers are morons" chalkboard. - You have to add a preprocessing step with a real XML toolkit to merge your separated files into a single one their library can grok.

Comment: Not saying they use the subset, just not 100% sure they don't. I just wanted to point out that this solution needs testing.